# a rehearsal for a gunfight set

Tags: word-choice

This is an excerpt from a [*The Atlantic* article](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2022/02/gun-safety-hollywood-alec-baldwin/622836/).

> Hutchins was killed on October 21, 2021—just 12 days into the filming
> of Rust—during a rehearsal for a gunfight **set** in a church on the
> outskirts of Santa Fe, New Mexico.

I think the **'set'** in bold should be replaced with 'scene'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You can rewrite the sentence to say that Hutchins was killed during a rehearsal for a gunfight **which was set** in a church (etc).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey or adding a comma: "...just 12 days into the filming of Rust—during a rehearsal for a gunfight, set in a church..." But then I admit it adds another punctuation mark which can look clunky.

Comment: @BruceWayne, or "rehearsal, for a gunfight set in a church"... :)

Comment: As in your other question today about *run*, you mistook a passive participle (which in both cases has the same form as the root verb) for a noun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can understand your confusion, but no, the Atlantic is not incorrect.  The trouble is, "set" has many different definitions.  Take a look at its [wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set)!  Four different etymologies and dozens of definitions for each!

You are likely thinking that this "set" is "the scenery for a film or play."  If this was correct, then "scene" might be a better word.

However, the actual meaning of "set" in this sentence is not even a noun.  It's a verb.  "(transitive) To locate (a play, etc.); to assign a backdrop to, geographically or temporally."

Another way you could rephrase the sentence, and keep the same meaning, would be:

> **Original:** ...during a rehearsal for a gunfight *set* in a church...
> **Variation:** ...during a rehearsal for a gunfight *located* in a church...

Both of these sentences are fine, and there is nothing wrong with the original.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I would argue that there is something wrong with the original: its ambiguity. How do you know that "set" is used as a synonym for "located" and not as a synonym for "scene"? I don't think there is a way to tell.

Comment: @Stef The sentence wouldn't make sense if it meant 'scenery for a film/play', because you don't have a rehearsal for the scenery. 'Scene' with the meaning 'a continuous segment of the play/film' would fit, but 'set' doesn't share that meaning with 'scene'.

Answer (score 0):

"set" here is the past participle of the verb "set". Confusingly, the past participle of the verb "set" is the same as both the present tense of "set" and the noun "set". Given such a variety of meaning for the same form, the sentence would have been much easier to read if it had been "Hutchins was killed on October 21, 2021—just 12 days into the filming of Rust—during a rehearsal for a gunfight **that was** set in a church on the outskirts of Santa Fe, New Mexico."

Also, while the past participle "set" derives from the verb "set", here it heads a phrase modifying "gunfight", thereby fulfilling a function that is usually performed by adjectives.

Comment: I would upvote this except for the word “grapheme”. Did you perhaps mean “lexeme”?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: IMHO, just call it a "word" and don't try to use the ten dollar linguistics terms unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @Kevin I agree.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I don't think "lexeme" is right right either; as I understand it, different conjugations of there same verb are considered the same lexeme.

Comment: @Kevin I'm trying to emphasize the particular sequence of letters. set-the-noun and set-the-verb are in some sense different words that happen to be spelled and pronounced the same.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Well, regardless, "grapheme" is definitely wrong, because in the context of the Latin alphabet (the writing system which English uses), a grapheme is a letter, numeral, or punctuation mark.